# Python pint convert 1/°Fahrenheit to 1/°Celsius

Tags: python, temperature, unit-conversion, pint

I use the python package [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/) and want to calculate e.g. 1 m/°F to m/°C.

```
from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg = UnitRegistry() #autoconvert_offset_to_baseunit = True
quantity = ureg.Quantity
fromvalue = quantity(1, ureg.parse_expression("m/°F"))
result = fromvalue.to(ureg.parse_expression("m/°C"))

print(result)
```

I get the error: "OffsetUnitCalculusError: Ambiguous operation with offset unit (meter, degree_Fahrenheit). See https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/nonmult.html for guidance.".

I read the explanation from the page linked in the error message. It helps to understand the problem, but doesn't provide a solution.

If I use `ureg = UnitRegistry(autoconvert_offset_to_baseunit = True)` or `as_delta=False` in the parsing, I get `1 meter / kelvin` as a reault, which is wrong.

I am expecting `1 m/°F -> 5/9 m/°C` as calculated by hand below?

```
1 m/°F        = x m/°C 
1 m/Δ°F       = x m/Δ°C 
1 m/(9/5 Δ°C) = x m/Δ°C 
5/9 m/Δ°C     = x m/Δ°C 
5/9 m/Δ°C     = 5/9 m/Δ°C  

1 m/°F -> 5/9 m/°C
```

One additional complication is that I'm making a function to convert values from one unit to another, so conversions e.g. from °F to °C should still work with the settings.

Comment: Look at your calculation.  You are using **delta** degrees C/F, `parse_expression("m/delta_degF")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong string representation for the unit you actually want.

```
>>> quantity(1, ureg.parse_expression("m/Δ°F"))
<Quantity(1, 'meter / delta_degree_Fahrenheit')>
```

Comment: Thats the solution!